# generate only valid utf-8 character string python 2

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, decode, encode, unichar

I am trying to generate a valid utf-8 character string using python 2.

```
def validate_mychar(cd_rng):
    return unichr(cd_rng)

def get_utf8_char():
    while True:
        cd_rng = random.randint(0x100, 0xFFFF)
        if validate_mychar(cd_rng):
            return unichr(cd_rng)

def utf8_gen(length):
    return u''.join(get_utf8_char() for i in xrange(length))


print(utf8_gen(10000))
```

But I wonder why I am getting strange 'invalid character' while using these characters. Can anybody help with a working code?

Comment: Your approach may produce [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates), which can't be encoded to UTF-8 – at least in Python 3 trying this throws an exception. But there are some questions here: Where do you think UTF-8 encoding is happening? In your code, I only see Unicode strings (not UTF-8-encoded strings!). Which codepoints cause the 'invalid character' exception? Which line causes the exception?

Comment: I am not much aware of UTF8. I want to generate some random utf8 string and use it.
```
    try:
        mych=unichr(code)
  mych.decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeError:
```
When I enclosed this block with try. catch block I see exceptions.

Comment: If you want to get a UTF-8-encoded byte string, you need to *encode*, not *decode*. The traceback tells you which line is causing the exception. Please edit the question rather than pasting code into comments, which is hard to read. – Are you sure you really want a UTF-8 string, not a Unicode string? Are you aware that handling Unicode is much more painful in (end-of-life!) Python 2, which is one of the main reasons why most people have switched to Python 3 long ago.

Comment: We are running applications which are using python2 and we can't just move to python3. 
yes, I am sure I want a UTF-8 string. And sure I will edit the question instead of posting comments.